# Sql Exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, sql-server

The website are able to run but when I try to login to the website, I get this error:

> SQL Exception was unhandled by user code

on this line =>

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Below is my code for my `DBmanager` for login in:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TopJobAgencyApp.Class
{
    public class DBManager
    {
        public static int InsertLogin(Registration u)
        {
            int rowsinserted = 0;

            SqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TopJobdb"].ConnectionString;
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO topJobUser(username, email, password)" +
                                   " VALUES (@username, @email, @password)";
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", u.UserName);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", u.Email);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", u.Password);

                rowsinserted = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            return rowsinserted;
        }
    }
}
```

The following pictures below are the error messages
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqqlD.png)

Comment: You are catching a SqlException And throwing it again. You need to handle it instead.

Comment: Please, show the error message `e.Message`

Comment: It will be interesting to know the InnerException message to fix the real problem

Comment: You need to inspect the `e.Errors` collection to see what concrete error was thrown

Comment: Looking at the error you will have to fix the username in your connection string. Also you should be closing the connection when you are done with it. Preferably put the connection in a using block.

Comment: Instead of `throw e;`, use just `throw;`. This will preserve the stack details so that you can see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is fairly clear:

> Login failed for user 'user'.

This means that the user associated with the connection string does not have login rights to the SQL Server in question.

**Possible resolutions**:

1. Validate the user has login rights to the SQL Server and then validate the credentials in the connection string.
2. If you are using Windows Authentication under IIS, you will need to set the Authentication mode to Windows (see sample below).
3. If using Entity Framework (based on the sample code, you're not), then you may need to remove the `Integrated Security=True` from the connection string; and possible remove the `User Instance=True` from the connection string as well.

Sample web.config for authentication mode of Windows:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

Let's chat about the posted code a bit...

***Return Type***

```
public static int InsertLogin(Registration u)
```

What is the purpose of returning an int? When using ExecuteNonQuery the result is the total number of rows affected which could include rows affected from an insert trigger. In most cases, an insert method should either return the identity of the newly inserted row or the actual new entity inserted.

***Disposing of the Connection***

```
conn = new SqlConnection();
```

SqlConnection (as does SqlCommand) implements IDisposible so you'd want to use the using statement to easily close/dispose of the connection.

***Try/Catch***

```
try
{
    // sql
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

What is the purse of catching and then throwing without any exception handling? i.e., logging, retrying, etc... Regardless, if an exception does need to get rethrown, then just use `throw`; by using `throw e` you're losing the stack trace.

***Adding parameters***

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", u.UserName);
```

Although AddWithValue works, it is a better practice to add the parameters with the types defined. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for more information.

***Refactor***

Now that we some background, the method can be cleaned up:

```
// not ideal, but let's hold the connection string in a backing field
// would be better if the connection string could be passed in at runtime
// instead of the data access layer needing direct access to the config file
private static readonly string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TopJobdb"].ConnectionString;

public static void InsertLogin(Registration u)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO topJobUser(username, email, password) VALUES (@username, @email, @password)";

        // be sure to set the size value correctly
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = u.UserName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = u.Email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = u.password;

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- There is no try/catch since there's nothing to recover from and no other exception handling is being managed.
- The method is returning void since the number of rows returned doesn't provide any information to the consumer.
- If you want to return the identity of the row inserted, there are several examples that an be searched.

Answer (score -2):

First, if you want to handle exceptions, you should not "throw" errors. The idea of exception handling is to "handle" the exception and not crash your app.

What you are doing here is that you are catching the exception and throwing it back.

You should modify your code to display a friendly error message and investigate the exception message and any other inner exceptions that might be there.

The the exception object that you create, e. You will find lots of useful information stored in its properties. You should explore the Source, Message, Inner Exceptions .. etc.

Second, from your error message, it seems that the login credentials are wrong. Make sure that your username and password are correct. Also, check the connection string is in order.

You could also set Break Points and check your code during execution.

Comment: It's OK to crash application after exception. Exception should be handled only when you know, how to restore application state after exception, otherwise exception must not be caught. Also, displaying error messages isn't universal solution.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that is is OK to crash an application. But I guess you need to do some programming and learn error handling properly. You need to handle exceptions at all times. And it is up to you as a developer to handle application state and what the user will see. For web apps, for example, instead of "crashing" the application, you could display a friendly error message to the user and then email the developer with the details. or log the error somewhere for later reference. Read about exception handling to further strengthen your knowledge.